# How do I use an EID card reader with Firefox on Ubuntu 21.10 and Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, apt, firefox

EID card-reader can read an ID card but it can't log in with the latest Mozilla Firefox on my health. I installed the add-on in Firefox. When I start Firefox I get a message:

> Eid software not found, do you have the latest version of  the Belgium EID software  is it installed  and up to date?

How I installed the drivers:

```
sudo dpkg -1 Downloads/eid-archive_2020.1all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eid-mw eid-viewer
```

In the EID viewer, I can read the ID card.

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of Firefox you are using, if it is the snap package of firefox, then it will not work, because snap packages cannot load `pkcs11` libs.

So if you are using the snap version, then try the deb package of firefox.

Comment: i  use   the version firefox v 94.0  that  is in ubuntu 20.04 then it update automatically ,  now i am  so far that  i  can use it  but  i have to plug it in and out,to work  and to make sure there is a id card in it means  when i   have  to check id cards  its a lot of plugging in and out